# Can't set focus to ScrollView using Qt.ClickFocus

Tags: qt, qml, focus, scrollview, qt6

I just want my TextField to lose focus when i click on ScrollView, but the problem is scrollview does not accept the focus using Qt.ClickFocus.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls.Universal

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 600
    height: 400

    ScrollView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        focusPolicy: Qt.ClickFocus

        TextField {
            id: textField
            implicitWidth: 400
            implicitHeight: 50
        }
    }
}
```

I think there is something interfering the click event because when i use
`focusPolicy: Qt.TabFocus`
it works perfectly just fine.

I'm using Qt 6.5. Is this a freaking bug?

[Update]
I just solve the problem using Stephen Quan answer

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls.Universal
import QtQuick.Layouts

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 600
    height: 400

    ScrollView {
        id: scrollView
        anchors.fill: parent

        ColumnLayout {
            id: columnLayout
            TextField {
                Layout.preferredWidth: 400
            }
        }
        
        TapHandler { 
            onTapped: columnLayout.forceActiveFocus() 
        }
    }
}
```

I just used the columnLayout so I don't have to explicitly set contentWidth and contentHeight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use a placeholder `Item` that's a child of the `ScrollView` as well as install a `TapHandler` for the `ScrollView` that calls that `Item`'s `forceActiveFocus()`:

```
    ScrollView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        TextField {
            id: textField
            implicitWidth: 400
            implicitHeight: 50
        }
        Item { id: placeholderItem }
        TapHandler { onTapped: placeholderItem.forceActiveFocus() }
    }
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAABQnicbY0/D4IwEMV3PkVHXQiDLt2MCcFNotG5aQ+4eLRNOf8khO8uEBWJvunu/d67w9q7wCLn/Ir6EuFsjbfOcnDURHtVgmgj0euge4dOCPeXMUhZXbnQxAUSSeFVAMsfeIQHpwhkvgqD0EjBbzYntSfUyGc0XEmxSpK/OAMsK5ZiPeHuM+0YatGOTzwpDZUjA2F0p9BR+UxZQxD6qLP96uG3EBcuaNhoxhukTl+bxfJ1o4u6JyQMXvY=)

Comment: Thanks!! But, is that a bug in ScrollView?

Comment: No. When TextField has focused, ScrollView has focused too. When you click on ScrollView, it's like, huh, the ScrollView already has focus so there's no need for it to do anything. So, the only way to steal focus from TextField is to declare another ScrollView child.

Comment: Ohh. I see, that makes a lot of sense. Thanks man, you are freaking priceless!!